# SQL Server "Deny View Any Database To" in stored proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a script which generates a database for a given {databaseName}, and then creates a login for a given {loginName} for this database.

I then want restrict this user to only be able to view this database, and no others.

I have this working through the use of:

```
USE [{DatabaseName}]
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[{DatabaseName}] to [{LoginName}]
GO
USE [master]
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [{LoginName}]
GO
```

I have now put this into a stored procedure, but I cannot change to the [master] database to execute the last line:

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [{LoginName}]
```

Is there a way to restrict the user from seeing other database from within a stored procedure?

The stored procedure is currently on another database, but I am able to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the database context for a given SQL command by doing something like this:

```
master.dbo.sp_executesql N'print db_name()'
```

Although I suspect there might be a better way to do what you're trying to do